# OpenVPN: Add clients without rebuilding all keys?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've just managed to setup OpenVPN properly on my server and test it to be properly working with client computers and I came to wonder how OpenVPN keys can be generated as clients come and go.

Is it necessary to rebuild the Diffie-Hellman `.dh` file and recreate all previous client keys as I just need to add or remove a client?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ency says, provided you've created your own CA, you simply create another key for the new user.  Before any more gets typed, when you set up openVPN you did create your own CA, as recommended, didn't you?

Edit: OK, then

```
cd easy-rsa
. ./vars
./build-key newclient
```

I also have some notes somewhere about making a CRL, which allows you to revoke old certificates, and pointing openVPN at the crl, but I can't immediately find them.

Comment: Yep! I did - the `ca.crt` file have been proven to be working!

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your edit, but doesn't this mean I have to rebuild the diffie helman? What would I need to do when I need to revoke access?

Comment: You could rebuild the main CA key and redistribute it, or you can make a CRL - Certificate Revocation List.  This is a list of certificates which despite being validly signed are no longer valid, in a very particular format, and also signed by your CA certificate.  The openVPN doco will point you at how to do it, it's not complex, just fiddly.  Once you've reconfigured your opeVPN server to use your CRL, keeping your CRL up-to-date is fairly straightforward.

Comment: So only the CA key would need to be redistributed and no other keys?

Comment: If you regenerate the CA, *all* keys will have to be redistributed (because the root signing key will be new, so all the other keys will need re-signing).  If you create a CRL, *no* keys have to be redistributed.

Comment: .crt file is not generated for me. only .csr and .key files

Comment: @MohammedShareefC this question is nearly nine years old, and things have probably changed a bit in the OpenVPN world since then.  Please consider asking a new question, linking to this one if you want (it shows you've done some research) and **showing**(not telling) us what you've done, what you saw as a result, and how it differed from what you expected to see.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:
I have got my own Certificate Authority and anytime I need new client I just create another certificate. It is simple and I am pretty sure you can do same thing even with `easyRSA` delivered with openVPN.
It is also more universal, because you can easily manage certificates for another services such as apache, etc.

Comment: How does that work with revoking access to a client?

Comment: There is a CRL list and you can easily revoke any certificate and I am using this command `openssl ca -config conf/openssl.cnf -revoke newcerts/XX.pem -keyfile private/ca.key -cert ca/ca.crt`, list of certificates is stored in index.txt (of course depends on your openSSL config)

Answer (score 0):

Use duplicate-cn option and one key for all client or use easy-rsa for create user [certification](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/77-rsa-key-management.html).

Comment: That would mean that I had to redistribute a new key to all clients if I need to restrict access to one user?

Comment: Yes that is correct !

Answer (score 0):

You can also tie the CN (that houses the user login name) of the user cert to a login that you can administer, for example, with FreeRADIUS. I wrote a small integration script couple of years ago. This way you can simply block user access by removing them from FreeRADIUS user list. The idea is that the certificate will protect the VPN from anyone else, and the FreeRADIUS login from the user itself (should the user's login need to be revoked). You can find the script and additional detail [here](http://random.ac/cess/2013/09/21/openvpn-with-freeradius-common-name-as-username/).

Answer (score 0):

Tested on OpenVPN 2.4.7 on Windows 7. I followed those steps:

1. Open CMD with Admin Rights.
2. Move to **easy-rsa** directory, within OpenVPN directory.
3. Run `vars.bat`.
4. Run `clean-all.bat`.
5. Make sure **ca.key** and **ca.crt** in the directory **keys**, which has just been created by the `clean-all.bat`.
6. Run `build-key A_New_Client`.
7. There will be **A_New_Client.crt**, **A_New_Client.csr** and **A_New_Client.key**. Those are the files specific to the new client. Copy them somewhere.
8. For safety reasons, shred the directory **keys** above.

It is assumed that `vars.bat` hasn't been changed since the last time, especially the key size part, as well as **openssl-1.0.0.cnf** is kept default.